# Replace a string "a < ? AND b > ?" by array [1, 2] to be "a > 1 AND b < 2"

Tags: javascript

I code a function like be low:

```
str = "a < ? AND b > ?"
replace = [1, 2]
for(i = 0; i < replace.length; i++)
{
    str = str.replace("?", replace[i]);
}
```

It is correct as expected: `"a > 1 AND b < 2"`

But when I try by another statement: `replace = ["?", 2]`.

The result will be: `"a < 2 AND b > ?"`

How I can replace the string in this case.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I try to make a simple example. But you can image if one item of the replacement is exist in the others. Sorry for my English.

Comment: The original string is `"a < ? AND b > ?"`, but then you say `It is correct as expected: "a > 1 AND b < 2"`. Why does the comparison operator change direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should start the search after the index of previous search at each iteration.
JavaScript has not a `replace` method that accepts `start` parameter, so I done it by finding the index of `"?"` and make the replace using `substring` method:

```js
var str = "a < ? AND b > ?";
var replace = ["?", 2];
var index  = 0; 
for(i = 0; i < replace.length; i++)
{
    index = str.indexOf("?",index);
    str = str.substring(0,index) + replace[i] +  str.substring(index+1);
    index++;
}
alert(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two elements in your array. So you will call the replace method twice (once on each pass of the loop).

In the first example this is what happens:

```
"a < ? AND b > ?" to  
"a < 1 AND b > ?" to
"a < 1 AND b > 2"
```

In the example you think you have problems it works like this:

```
"a < ? AND b > ?" to  
"a < ? AND b > ?" to HERE you are replacing a question mark with a question mark.
"a < 2 AND b > ?"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should split **str** to **_array** (_array of words) and then replace this **_array** by **_replace** (your array).

Example:

```
str       = "a < ? AND b > ?"
_replace  = [1, 2]
_array    = str.plit(" ") //["a","<","?","AND","b",">","?"];
index     = 0
for(i = 0; i < _array.length; i++)
{
    if( replace[i] === "?" )
    {
        _array[i] = _replace[index]
        index++
    }
}
str = _array.join(" ")
```